# Alternative to ssh-copy-id on windows

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh, rsa, ssh-keygen

I want to copy an SSH public key to a remote device on Windows. I'm not using PuTTYgen rather just OpenSSH through PowerShell. I ran

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

And it gave me a public and private key in my .ssh folder but if I try to do

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub <name@machine>
```

I get the same error:

> ssh-copy-id : The term 'ssh-copy-id' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
> program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Perhaps the ssh-copy-id command was meant for Linux, but I was able to get some other commands meant for Linux to run.

How do I copy the key from my Windows laptop to my remote machine? Is it even possible to do just in Windows without an app like PuTTYgen?

Comment: Have a look at this https://serverfault.com/questions/224810/is-there-an-equivalent-to-ssh-copy-id-for-windows

Answer (score 2):

(given id_rsa.pub exists as when previously generated with "ssh-keygen -t rsa")

This single line answer is barely the same as that given by [barlop](https://superuser.com/users/42672/barlop) without cygwin, mentioning that with windows native ssh it works as well...

```
C:\\> type %USERPROFILE%\\.ssh\\id_rsa.pub | ssh user@host "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Answer (score 1):

All you are actually doing is adding the contents of your id_rsa.pub file to your ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on your linux host.  (You may need to run 'systemctl restart ssh'.)

On your windows machine you then use the -i parameter:

> ssh -i {path to private key file}\id_rsa {name}@{machine}

If you used a passphrase you will be prompted for that, otherwise it will let you right in.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I've got cygwin installed, and that has ssh and includes ssh-copy-id (which is a script btw).

```
$ which ssh-copy-id
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id
```

By the way if you get an error like what you got then a basic troubleshooting step to simplify is just to try `$ ssh-copy-id <ENTER>`  so as you know it's nothing to do with all the parameters you put after ssh-copy-id.

This article mentions the manual method of ssh-copy-id
https://chrisjhart.com/Windows-10-ssh-copy-id/

```
type $env:USERPROFILE\.ssh\id_rsa.pub | ssh {IP-ADDRESS-OR-FQDN} "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

and he gives an example

```
PS C:\Users\Christopher> type $env:USERPROFILE\.ssh\id_rsa.pub | ssh 192.168.30.31 "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

a bit more info, related [To use ssh-id-copy do you need both id_rsa.pub and id_rsa?](https://superuser.com/questions/874406/to-use-ssh-id-copy-do-you-need-both-id-rsa-pub-and-id-rsa)